# Where to post a question about host configurations/issues

Tags: discussion, scope, site-recommendation

My question is something like this:

> We are using Windows 2019 Server in our office, and the host PC uses Windows 10 mostly. Sometimes after the login credentials are entered, the OS doesn’t load completely. It keeps trying to load or just a blackish (not black) screen appears for unlimited time (then we must force shut down and restart again, and sometimes it just goes away after the restart and sometimes the problem persists).

Comment: If you can reproduce the issue without being connected to a local network, then https://superuser.com; if it's depending on your office network then https://serverfault.com. (Actually, maybe Super User anyway; read both on-topic help pages first.) Either way you are definitely going to need more debugging detail than that, unless the question is specifically about how to collect debugging info.

Comment: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/85312/29837

Comment: On a sidenote, a video of the screen going black after login is not useful to help debug this. Just stating so in text gets the message across much more efficiently.

Comment: "We are using Windows 2019 Server in our office" -> Is that really all that is used or is there a thick layer of added security software installed as well? I have a similar issue at the office, it happens when logging in too quickly before certain policies have loaded. No idea which, no way to know which. As such, zero chance to ask a successful question about it.

Answer (score 1):

You need way more debug information and several configuration options before you can reask that question.

Your question needs (as text):

- relevant application eventlog entries
- relevant system eventlog entries
- relevant [boot log](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/advanced-startup-options-including-safe-mode-b90e7808-80b5-a291-d4b8-1a1af602b617)
- BIOS diagnostics and/or memory diagnostics
- any errors/warnings from the sfc and dism tools
- additional components log entries after you enabled the logging for suspect components
- behavior of the system after booting in any of the Safe modes, with and without networking
- BIOS model / version, hardware setup.

After you gathered all this information, you either found the root cause by googling or have enough information to give an updated version of your question a try on [Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic).